# Override values in analysis_options.yaml

Tags: dart, flutter

When including an `analysis_options.yaml`, should it be possible to extend/override some of its values?

I have the following setup:

**`shared/analysis_options.yaml:`**

```
analyzer:
  exclude:
    - generated/**
```

**`my_app/analysis_options.yaml:`**

```
include: ../shared/analysis_options.yaml

analyzer:
  exclude:
    - lib/localization/messages_*.dart
```

I am unable to build `my_app` because the `message_*.dart` files that I'm trying to exclude are not in fact excluded from analysis.

However, if I comment out the line `include: ../shared/analysis_options.yaml`, the app builds.

Comment: Check issues in dart-lang/sdk. Exclude doesn't work well yet.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is when you add exclude path that is not in quotation marks. I have config below and it works just right. Feel free to try it.

```
include: package:pedantic/analysis_options.yaml

analyzer:
  strong-mode:
    implicit-casts: false
    implicit-dynamic: false
  exclude:
    - "**/*.g.dart"
  errors:
    missing_return: error
    missing_required_param: error
```